# Problems with Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, citrix, invoke-command, scriptblock

Hey Guys im new to StackOverflow and I'm here to ask a Question about my Powershell Script for the Automation of a Script on my mgmt Server to all XENAPP Servers im hosting. I want to execute with one click the Citrix Optimizer to every XENAPP. This is my Code... btw i am a complete beginner to PowerShell.

```
#Citrix Optimizer for every Server

$templates= "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\templates"
$Program= "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\CtxOptimizerEngine.ps1"
$computer= Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=*xxxxxxxxxxxx*)" -SearchBase "OU=Test Server,OU=CVAD1912,OU=Server,DC=xxxxxxxxxxx,DC=xx"
$computername=$computer.name

foreach ($server in $computername){

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{

$using:Program} -Source AutoSelect from $templates -Mode Analyze
    
}
```

My error Code is:

```
Invoke-Command : Es wurde kein Parameter gefunden, der dem Parameternamen "Source" entspricht.
In C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\CitrixOptimizer.ps1:14 Zeichen:17
+ $using:Program} -Source AutoSelect from $templates -Mode Analyze
+                 ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I know... My Visual Code is in German but i hope you can help me.

FYI: in the code are some things just filled up with x, this is just not to leak something personal. I guess it should not affect your help.

Appreciate the Help!

Best cosmo_

Comment: Can you show the output from `Get-Command \\path\to\CtxOptimizerEngine.ps1 -Syntax`?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Source` I assume the -Source parameter is intended for `CtxOptimizerEngine.ps1` and not as a parameter for Invoke-Command?

Comment: Hey Guys, I finally found the error!

If you are interested what it was:

`$using:Program -Source Auto-Select from $templates -Mode Analyze`

This was the original code. But i saw that i already used AutoSelect and I won't need the from $templates anymore.
And @notjustme you were right. but I were also able to fix that.
Thanks Guys for helping me so that I were able to do it. 
Best cosmo_